# How to link my search filter with my listcomponent in angular?

Tags: angular, list, typescript, components

I've made a list and a search-bar with an implemented filter function.

Here is my search-bar with my filter function.

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput #message maxlength="256" 
          placeholder="Type vehicle name" (input)='filter(message.value)' >
            <mat-hint align="start"><strong>Find vehicle</strong> </mat-hint>
            <mat-hint align="end">{{message.value.length}} / 256</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Here is my list

```
 <div>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let stuff of vehicleDetails">
       <a matLine> {{ stuff.name }} </a>
       <button mat-icon-button id="btn" (mouseover)="showInfo(stuff)">
          <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
       </button>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-nav-list>

</div>
```

These two are in the same .html file and they share a component.ts file. The list is generated by calling a getVehicleDetails() in my ngOnInit.

```
export class VehiclelistComponent implements OnInit {

vehicleDetails: VehicleDetail[] = [];


constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getVehicleDetails();
    }


 getVehicleDetails(): void {
   this.vehicleService.getVehicleDetails()
   .subscribe(vehicleDetails => {
  this.vehicleDetails = vehicleDetails;
   });
 }
```

And this is the function im using for filtering:

```
filter(searchToken: string) {
  if (searchToken == null) {
    searchToken = '';
  }
  searchToken = searchToken.toLowerCase();
  return this.vehicleDetails.filter((elem: VehicleDetail) => 
         elem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchToken) > -1);

  }
```

Why doesnt this work? The filter function doesnt have any impact on my list. Is there anyone who know how I can solve this?

Comment: Please do some troubleshooting, add a more detailed description of the problem ("_does_ _not_ _work_" is not helpful), the spected behaviour, if you get error what those error are... I would suggest checking the [help] page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to use (keyup) instead of (input) and then you have to re-bind your array with result of filter .. not return it from your method?

something like:

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput #message maxlength="256" 
          placeholder="Type vehicle name" [ngModel]="message.value" (keyup)='filter($event)' >
            <mat-hint align="start"><strong>Find vehicle</strong> </mat-hint>
            <mat-hint align="end">{{message.value.length}} / 256</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

then in your TS:

```
filter(ev: any) {
let searchToken = ev.target.value;

  if (searchToken == null) {
    searchToken = '';
  }
  searchToken = searchToken.toLowerCase();
this.message.value = searchToken; //here you update the UI (textbox) wth the value .. in this case is not necessary .. but if you wnat for example lowercase the string .. you can do by this
  this.vehicleDetails = this.vehicleDetails.filter((elem: VehicleDetail) => 
         elem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchToken) > -1); // HERE NOT RETUR  .. BUT FULL ARRAY BINDED WITH RESULT OF FILTER

  }
```

Another thing i suggest to you is .. don't work on your original array .. but clone it and owkr on it ..

something like:

```
export class VehiclelistComponent implements OnInit {

vehicleDetails: VehicleDetail[] = [];
vehicleDetailsCloned: VehicleDetail[] = [];

constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getVehicleDetails();
    }


 getVehicleDetails(): void {
   this.vehicleService.getVehicleDetails()
   .subscribe(vehicleDetails => {
  this.vehicleDetails = vehicleDetails;
this.vehicleDetailsCloned = [ ...vehicleDetails]; //cloned with spread operator
   });
 }


filter(searchToken: string) {
  if (searchToken == null) {
    searchToken = '';
  }
  searchToken = searchToken.toLowerCase();
  this.vehicleDetails = searchToken.length>0 
        ? this.vehicleDetailsCloned.filter((elem: VehicleDetail) => 
                   elem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchToken) > -1)
        :  this.vehicleDetailsCloned ;

  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 
I have done some online courses in angular and they used $event as well. Is there any benefits by doing so instead of the template refering #message?
And what is the ngModel providing for us in this case?

I tried with your non-returning method as well before. What I didnt manage to do was to return the list to its original state when I erased the characters in the input-field. How come this problem is solved with the spread operator?
I appreciate the help!

Comment: the [ngModel] is the one way data bindning on textbox (so tonshow updated value in ui) .. chekc my update on the code ... spread operator ( [ ...] or { ... } ) is used like array.concat and also do a clone ...